# Canvas fill reflects on both the shapes

Tags: javascript, canvas

have created 2 canvas shape,

want to fill different colors in both the shape. However changing color of 2nd shape reflects in first shape as well.

Here is my code

```
//Drawing 1st triangle color #FFCC000 Triangle
ctx.moveTo(rectX - 100, rectY);
ctx.lineTo(rectX, rectY - 100);
ctx.lineTo(rectX, rectY);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFCC00";
ctx.fill();

//Drawing  2nd Triangle - color #CC00CC 
    ctx.moveTo(rectX+220, rectY);
    ctx.lineTo(rectX+220, rectY - 100);
    ctx.lineTo(rectX+300, rectY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CC00CC";
    ctx.fill();
```

if i draw only 1 triangle, it reflects proper color. However when showing both triangle, both of them takes color of 2nd triangle #CC00CC

How can i apply different colors to both??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `closePath` and `beginPath`:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(rectX - 100, rectY);
ctx.lineTo(rectX, rectY - 100);
ctx.lineTo(rectX, rectY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFCC00";
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
//Drawing  2nd Traingle - color #CC00CC 
ctx.moveTo(rectX+220, rectY);
ctx.lineTo(rectX+220, rectY - 100);
ctx.lineTo(rectX+300, rectY);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "#CC00CC";
ctx.fill();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bn4dwpL/1/)